# If $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \ x_{n} = a$ then why does it exist a subsquence $s_{n}$, which $\lim_{n\to\infty} \ s_{n} = a$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, alternative-proof, limsup-and-liminf

Maybe it seems trivial since $\limsup$ is known as the "greatest limit point of $x_n$", so there's a subsequence which converges to $a$. But I cannot use this definition. Is it possible to prove it without using this definition of $\limsup$? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You want to prove

> $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=a\;$ **implies** $\;a$ is a subsequential limit of $\{x_n\}$

See if you can get a contradiction from

> $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=a\;$ **and** $\;a$ is not a subsequential limit of $\{x_n\}$

In particular, see if you can prove the following: If $a$ is not a subsequential limit of $\{x_n\},$ then there exists an open interval centered at $a$ that contains no terms of the sequence (or if you want, all you need to show is that there is an open interval containing $a$ that contains no terms of the sequence). From this result you should be able to obtain a contradiction to "$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=a$", regardless of what definition you use for $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n.$ Regarding the "see if you can prove" part, note that if no such open interval exists, then you can pick terms from the sequence belonging to open intervals with center $a$ having arbitrarily small lengths, and these chosen terms will form a subsequence converging to $a.$

Comment: Sorry but there are terms I don't know yet (ball centered, open neighborhood)

Comment: Ooops, the context is clearly sequences in $\mathbb R,$ whereas I was writing as if it could possibly be sequences in some other space. Instead of "ball centered at $a$" read "interval with center $a,$" and instead of "open neighborhood" read "open interval".